# Ensuring react components aren't broken up when printing

Tags: reactjs

I am making a resume creation tool with React and have a print screen at the end. Whilst the parent components can go over multiple pages, there are a few small child components (2-5 lines) that can't be broken up over multiple pages.

I haven't been able to find a workable solution using CSS or JSS

```
function IndividualJob(props) {
    const {job} = props;
    return (
        <strong>{job.position}</strong><br></br>
        <em>{job.timeframe}</em><br></br>
        {job.comments}<br></br>
        <br></br>
    );
}

function Jobs() {
    return (
        <>
            {cv.jobs.map((job) => <IndividualJob job={job}/>}
        </>
    );
}
```

I want to have the IndividualJob components not broken up by the page break.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer that worked in my case. I just added

```
@media print {
    div {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

To prevent components from being broken up

Answer (score 0):

I know this was 3 years ago, but I had similar situation recently, in addition to the previous answer here for page-break-inside, I also changed the scaling when printing to pdf to match the results I needed.